# I have defined 2 text strings, how do I use them in my posts?

Tags: functions, plugin-wpml

If you define a text string in the child theme functions file, how do you call for those inside your posts?

I added 2 phrases to use over and over in a table, I want to translate them with WPML, I was able to import them, however, now I do not know how to put the code inside my html block to call for the text and allow WPML to translate it if you change languages.

Hope you can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I end up using this:

[wpml-string context='domain']TEXT[/wpml-string]

Re-scanned and the new phrases appeared, I put the same code in my post in the second language and it was translated.